# Trying to achieve the Word equivalent of "style for following paragraph"

Tags: lyx, exam, lyx-layouts

In MSWord, when defining a paragraph style, it's possible to define the style of the following paragraph (the style that will chosen when I type <kbd>return</kbd> after entering the text of the style). This is practical, since some paragraphs such as headings are followed by normal style, whereas numbered lists are followed by the same list style.

[image]

In LyX I'm using a customized `.layout` for the [Exam class in LaTeX](http://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf). Ultimately the LaTeX has to look something like:

```
\begin{questions}
\question[2]
What is your quest?
\question[2]
What is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow?
...
\end{questions}
```

I've defined a Flex inset for the `questions` environment as:

```
InsetLayout "Flex:Questions"
    LabelFont
        Family Sans
        Series Bold 
    EndFont
    Decoration  Classic
    BgColor insetbg
    LyxType Custom
    LatexName   questions
    LatexType   Environment
    LabelString "Questions block"
    ResetsFont true
End
```

Then I'm entering `\question`s by selecting the **Question** style in the drop-down menu. It is defined as follows:

```
Style Question
    CopyStyle       Enumerate
    LatexType       Command
    LeftMargin      "MM"
    LatexName       question
    ParSkip         0.4
    Align           Left
    LabelType       Static
    LabelCounter    questionnumber
    LabelString     "\arabic{questionnumber}."
    Category        Questions        
    Argument        1
        LabelString "Points"
        Tooltip     "Number of points, e.g., 1, 2, 5, "
        AutoInsert  1
    EndArgument
End
```

Everything works. However, I'm trying to tweak it so that after pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> at the end of a question, the *next* paragraph's style is also the same as the last (e.g., Question). I'd like to set this up for all the question-related styles, e.g., `\part`, `\subpart`, etc., which all have their respective environment (like `\begin{questions} .. \end{questions}`. Also, `\choice` and/or `\CorrectChoice` are styles I'd like to work this way in the `\begin{choices}` environment.

I saw the support for `LatexType Item_Environment` in styles, but it seems it only adds `\item`s for each entry. I couldn't find a way to customize this so it adds a specific style, e.g., `\question`. Is there a way to achieve this in LyX?

**Edit** I'm using LyX 2.1.3 under Windows (7 and 8.1).

Comment: What happens if you do "alt + p, <Return>" instead of just <Return>? Does that do what you want? For example, if you ware in an enumerate and you have 1. first item 2. second item 3. third item, then do alt + p, <Return> you will have 1. first item.

Comment: @scottkosty "alt + p, <return>" does nothing when I'm on a Question as defined above. The message log for LyX says `Alt+P Return
Command disabled`

Comment: Does it work for enumerate for you? (I know this is not what you want, but just to make sure it works as expected). What version of LyX do you use?

Comment: TeX/LaTeX model is completely different. There's no concept of “style for the next paragraph”.

Comment: @scottkosty I updated the question with the version of LyX. Enumerations work in the sense that if I do "alt + p, E" (for numbered list) it creates an Enumerate style, and after typing return I get a subsequent Enumerate style. This is the behavior I'm trying to reproduce with a `.layout` for arbitrary customized styles.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I think I understand your question better. I tried some experimenting but did not succeed. If you do not find an answer here, please try on lyx-users@lists.lyx.org . There are some people there with a high knowledge of LyX's layout mechanism. If you are sure the feature does not exist, the make a feature request at http://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: Eight years ago, someone asked a related question at http://lyx-users.lyx.narkive.com/3RGUc265/lyx-layout-file-for-multiple-choice-exam-anybody-have-examdesign-layout-working *'This looks (to my untrained eye) exacly like a LaTeX list, except with different words, replacing "item" with "choice".'*

Comment: You have 2 returns after `\question` - not one...?

Comment: @egreg I agree with your statement. However, LyX does repeat Enumerate styles and LyX is more like Word than TeX/LaTeX.

Comment: Let's note for archival purposes that the OP cross-posted (and correctly linked back here) at: http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg101571.html

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I'm not sure that is true. If it is true, I'd say LyX ought to be considered off-topic here. However, I don't think it is. The underlying formatting is LaTeX and, as I understand it, it is difficult to use LyX effectively without some understanding of how LateX does things. (Not to say it isn't relatively easy to use without this - but that using it effectively to achieve customised formatting depends on an understanding of the underlying formatting.) So there is no reason to expect a Word function to make any sense as a LyX function because often it will not do so at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for a new feature in lyx.

Comment: @mico How do we know this is a request for a new feature? Do we know for sure it's *not* possible to make LyX add an arbitrarily named item to a list environment? (Just worried that this has been closed more due to LyX aversion than to the facts.)

Comment: @AlanMunn - I was looking at the exchange of comments between the OP and Scott Kosty. Naturally, my inference *could* be wrong. FWIW, while I'm not a lyx user, I'm not aware of any aversion to lyx on my part. :-)

Comment: No, I wasn't accusing you of such. :) But if it's not possible to do something, that doesn't make it a feature request. Surely an answer of "No it's not possible to do this because..." is a good answer. We have plenty similar answers on the site for other such questions. (e.g. editor features that people ask about.)

Comment: @Mico you had good intuition. I did not know that it was not possible, but Richard Heck (one of the experts of LyX's layout design) says that it is not currently possible: http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg101572.html

Comment: @AlanMunn I agree that the appropriate thing would be to reopen and to add an answer of "this is not possible", quoting Richard Heck in the link I put above.

Comment: I've voted to re-open the posting. Once it's re-opened, somebody can post a "No, this is not possible" answer. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible with a Flex inset, but it is possible with a list, as Jurgen Spitzmuller points out over on lyx-users.

```
Style Questions
  Margin           Static
  LatexType        Item_Environment
  LatexName        questions
  ItemCommand      question
  Argument item:1
    MenuString     "Point Value"
    LabelString    "Points"
  EndArgument
  LeftMargin       MMN
  LabelSep         xx
  LabelType        Enumerate
End
```

The key is the `ItemCommand`, which tells LyX what command to use for items in the environment. (Default, of course, is `\item`.)

Still, I think it's a natural idea to have a "next style" command for all kinds of layouts. Basically, what LyX does now is use the DefaultStyle, unless the current layout is an environment, in which case it uses the same style.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx (although you've been registered for a while). It's really nice to have your expertise on the site for LyX questions in particular, because due to the small number of LyX users here LyX questions often don't get the kinds of answers they deserve.

Comment: I played with this and it's interesting (I was focusing too much on flex insets because of nesting). Even the "increase depth" could be useful. However, I can't see a way to customize a separate environment for the lower depth, which changes in `exam.cls`, e.g., questions > parts > subparts > subsubparts). I think I must use flex insets because of this constraint, although I should have put this in my question. Also, the choices environment can be nested anywhere within this hierarchy.

Comment: If you refer to what is demonstrated in sec 4.2 of the exam manual: I do not see why this should not be possible with the style approach.

Comment: @JSpitzm Indeed, I did a quick test and nesting as shown in sec 4.2 works, provided one 1) chooses Increase depth and 2) changes the layout to the appropriate nested style. It would be beneficial if LyX could get hints from the layout to aim the user in the right direction of the nesting hierarchy with a style sequence (e.g., if I'm in Questions and I do increase depth, LyX could automatically switch to Parts).

Comment: Thanks again for the advice. Now it seems it's not adequate because several exam environments have alternates for ItemCommand. The bonus feature from sec 4.6 applies to questions, parts, subparts, subsubparts, and it means you can have e.g. \question or \bonusquestion within questions environment. A similar situation arrives with choices environment which allows \choice and \CorrectChoice. I'm not seeing how this approach can allow this.

Comment: It is not impossible, although there is no ideal way. You can just nest a standard paragraph within the choice list and prefix it with `\CorrectChoice` in TeXMode (or define a correct choice layout or InsetLayout).